# System.Math.Round bug?

Tags: .net, rounding

I was writing a function for rounding a number to two places. And I found a bug when I was trying to round specific values. So, I ran the code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int limit = 100;

        for (int number = 0; number <= limit; number++) {
            Console.WriteLine((System.Math.Round((double)(number+0.995),2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)));
        }
    }
}
```

And I found that:
**8.99
9.99**
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
**32.99
33.99
34.99
35.99
36.99
37.99
38.99
39.99**

numbers are not rounded to their next value.

When I run the same code till 1500: I get the numbers:

8.99
9.99
32.99
33.99
34.99
35.99
36.99
37.99
38.99
39.99
1024.99
1025.99
1026.99
1027.99
1028.99
1029.99
1030.99
1031.99
1032.99
1033.99
1034.99
1035.99
1036.99
1037.99
1038.99
1039.99
1040.99
1041.99
1042.99
1043.99
1044.99
1045.99
1046.99
1047.99
1048.99
1049.99
1050.99
1051.99
1052.99
1053.99
1054.99
1055.99
1056.99
1057.99
1058.99
1059.99
1060.99
1061.99
1062.99
1063.99
1064.99
1065.99
1066.99
1067.99
1068.99
1069.99
1070.99
1071.99
1072.99
1073.99
1074.99
1075.99
1076.99
1077.99
1078.99
1079.99
1080.99
1081.99
1082.99
1083.99
1084.99
1085.99
1086.99
1087.99
1088.99
1089.99
1090.99
1091.99
1092.99
1093.99
1094.99
1095.99
1096.99
1097.99
1098.99
1099.99
1100.99
1101.99
1102.99
1103.99
1104.99
1105.99
1106.99
1107.99
1108.99
1109.99
1110.99
1111.99
1112.99
1113.99
1114.99
1115.99
1116.99
1117.99
1118.99
1119.99
1120.99
1121.99
1122.99
1123.99
1124.99
1125.99
1126.99
1127.99
1128.99
1129.99
1130.99
1131.99
1132.99
1133.99
1134.99
1135.99
1136.99
1137.99
1138.99
1139.99
1140.99
1141.99
1142.99
1143.99
1144.99
1145.99
1146.99
1147.99
1148.99
1149.99
1150.99
1151.99
1152.99
1153.99
1154.99
1155.99
1156.99
1157.99
1158.99
1159.99
1160.99
1161.99
1162.99
1163.99
1164.99
1165.99
1166.99
1167.99
1168.99
1169.99
1170.99
1171.99
1172.99
1173.99
1174.99
1175.99
1176.99
1177.99
1178.99
1179.99
1180.99
1181.99
1182.99
1183.99
1184.99
1185.99
1186.99
1187.99
1188.99
1189.99
1190.99
1191.99
1192.99
1193.99
1194.99
1195.99
1196.99
1197.99
1198.99
1199.99
1200.99
1201.99
1202.99
1203.99
1204.99
1205.99
1206.99
1207.99
1208.99
1209.99
1210.99
1211.99
1212.99
1213.99
1214.99
1215.99
1216.99
1217.99
1218.99
1219.99
1220.99
1221.99
1222.99
1223.99
1224.99
1225.99
1226.99
1227.99
1228.99
1229.99
1230.99
1231.99
1232.99
1233.99
1234.99
1235.99
1236.99
1237.99
1238.99
1239.99
1240.99
1241.99
1242.99
1243.99
1244.99
1245.99
1246.99
1247.99
1248.99
1249.99
1250.99
1251.99
1252.99
1253.99
1254.99
1255.99
1256.99
1257.99
1258.99
1259.99
1260.99
1261.99
1262.99
1263.99
1264.99
1265.99
1266.99
1267.99
1268.99
1269.99
1270.99
1271.99
1272.99
1273.99
1274.99
1275.99
1276.99
1277.99
1278.99
1279.99
1280.99
1281.99
1282.99
1283.99
1284.99
1285.99
1286.99
1287.99
1288.99
1289.99
1290.99
1291.99
1292.99
1293.99
1294.99
1295.99
1296.99
1297.99
1298.99
1299.99
1300.99
1301.99
1302.99
1303.99
1304.99
1305.99
1306.99
1307.99
1308.99
1309.99

which are not rounded to next number! Has anyone any idea about why its happening for these specific numbers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that when you're taking the value of "number + 0.995", that's not going to be *exactly* number + 0.995 for the normal reasons of binary floating point not representing decimal values precisely.

Sometims it will be a little over, and sometimes it'll be a little under. When it's *under*, and you round that result to two decimal places, you end up with the "0.99" bit. It's possible that `Math.Round` tries to take this into account to some extent, but I'm not sure of the *exact* details.

The solution - where possible - is to use `decimal` instead of `double` for things where the *decimal digits* matter.

See my articles on [binary floating point](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/floatingpoint.html) and [decimal](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/decimal.html) floating point in .NET for more information.

Here's a program using my [DoubleConverter](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) code which shows the inaccuracy after adding 0.995:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            double d = i + 0.995;
            Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d));
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> 0.99499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
>   1.99500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
>   2.99500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
>   3.99500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
>   4.99500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
>   5.99500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
>   6.99500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
>   7.99500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875
>   8.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   9.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   10.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   11.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   12.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   13.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   14.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   15.9949999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625
>   16.995000000000000994759830064140260219573974609375
>   17.995000000000000994759830064140260219573974609375
>   18.995000000000000994759830064140260219573974609375
>   19.995000000000000994759830064140260219573974609375
>   20.995000000000000994759830064140260219573974609375
>   ...

(Note how although it *starts* going 0.994 at 8, it continues as far as 15 - whereas `Math.Round` "corrects" itself at 10.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. It helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a matter of a proper handling. Try to explain this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.995, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 5.00
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(5.995, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 6.00
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(9.995, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); // 9.99
```

As you can easily see, 1% is far greater than the double precision limit. And there are NO arithmetic operations which can be blamed for precision loss.

Math.Round and double.ToString() has different rounding behavior. Math.Round just doesn't works some times. I had to drop Math.Round and had to develop my own rounding to solve that.